# Centering the equations with inequalities

Tags: math-mode, alignment

This is the code I have, however the inequalities are not in the right place, I don't know why using for instance `\:\:\:` to move it to the right does not work.

```
   \begin{gather*}
        \qquad\begin{aligned}
            \min    &\quad   (x_1-2)^2+(x_2-0.2)^2       \\
            \mathrm{s.t}    &\quad \frac{5x_1^2sin(\pi \sqrt{s})}{1+s^2}\leq 0\:\:\forall s\in[0,1] \\
            -1\leq x_1 \leq 1 &\quad 0\leq x_2 \leq 2
              \end{aligned}
    \end{gather*}
```

I want to move the inequalities to the right obviousely, any help appreciated[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAvoL.png)

Comment: It was just \qquad in source, but I thought maybe adding an extra q would make a difference hence..

Comment: `\qqquad` is not defined.

Comment: Move the last line out side the `aligned` and remove the `&` from it. If you do not want it aligned with the first two lines, it should not be a part of that aligned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are saying in:

```
-1\leq x_1 \leq 1 &\quad 0\leq x_2 \leq 2
```

to align `-1\leq x_1 \leq 1` before the alignment column (like `\min` and `s.t`) and the other inequality after.

Maybe you meant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    \qquad\begin{aligned}
        \min    &\quad   (x_1-2)^2+(x_2-0.2)^2       \\
        \mathrm{s.t}    &\quad \frac{5x_1^2\sin(\pi \sqrt{s})}{1+s^2}\leq 0\:\:\forall s\in[0,1] \\
        & \quad -1\leq x_1 \leq 1 \quad 0\leq x_2 \leq 2
    \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted!

Comment: You forgot a backslash for the sine.

Comment: `sin` should be `\sin`; I understand it was like so in the OP's input, but it's better to fix errors when possible.

Comment: @egreg, thanks --- fixed (I missed it!)

Answer (score 2):

The reason your inequalities are so far to the left is because the `\quad` that separates them in the middle is aligned with the other `\quad`s that are mostly to the front of the lines.

You can try removing the inequalities from the `aligned` environment and put them after it within the `gather*` environment, like so.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
    \min    &\quad   (x_1-2)^2+(x_2-0.2)^2       \\
    \mathrm{s.t}    &\quad \frac{5x_1^2sin(\pi \sqrt{s})}{1+s^2}\leq 0\:\:\forall s\in[0,1]
\end{aligned} \\
-1 \leq x_1 \leq 1 \quad 0 \leq x_2 \leq 2
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```